# How to test in Doze and Standby modes

Tags: appium

Does Appium support Doze and Standby modes?

If not, how do I test a device in these modes?

[Optimizing for Doze and App Standby](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html)

Thanks.

Comment: The link you provide, I think, answers your own question - through the adb commands to set and stop doze and standby modes?  Based on your reputation level, I'm guessing you don't need an example on how to perform an adb command, so perhaps you can embellish your question?

Comment: Cool, just putting the question out there. Thanks for the feedback. I'll circle back to this problem when the time comes and post an answer.